# I have created a custom NER using spacy and i want to train it with additional data but what to change in config.cfg file?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have created a spacy NER model for named entity recognition and its having tok2vec and ner as components in the pipeline. Now i want to add some more data to it, so i am using a model-best directory from where I can load my trained model for predictions. If i follow the documentation without changing anything from config.cfg file then the newly created model-best have no information about it's previous trained data.

`! python -m spacy convert one.json ./ -t spacy`

`! python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg`

`! python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./ --paths.train ./one.spacy --paths.dev ./one.spacy`

After running them two folders got created (model-best and model-last)

now to train it with new data i tried like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
from tqdm import tqdm
import json

nlp=spacy.load('model-best')
f = open('two.json')
TRAIN_DATA = json.load(f)
```

```
db = DocBin()
for text, annot in tqdm(TRAIN_DATA['annotations']): 
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) 
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]:
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents 
    db.add(doc)

db.to_disk("./training_data.spacy")
```

`! python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg`

`! python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./ --paths.train ./training_data.spacy --paths.dev ./training_data.spacy`

After running them, it replaced my model-best folder with new one and it can only recognnise the new data now
what changes should i make in my config.cfg inorder to train it properly so that it can remember both old data and new data?

Answer (score 0):

To train over an existing model, you can define the source component in your `base_config.cfg`

```
[components.ner]
source = "<path_to_model-best>"
component = "ner"
```

This information is available on the spacy documentation website here:
https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#sourced-components